Error al guardar archivo PDF desde JasperReport
estoy teniendo un problema al intentar guardar un reporte en PDF desde JasperReport, el codigo de error que da es el siguiente
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/DocumentException
